# How to create a solr core using docker-solrs image extension mechanism?

Tags: docker, solr, dockerfile

I would like to create a docker image of solr that creates a core on startup. Therefore I'm using the [`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` extension mechanism](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/) described for solr docker containers. The documentation says

> The third way of creating a core at startup is to use the image
>   extension mechanism explained in the next section.

But it does not explain exactly how to achieve this.

The Dockerfile I'm using is:

```
FROM solr:6.6

USER root

RUN mkdir /A12Core && chown -R solr:solr /A12Core

COPY --chown=solr:solr ./services-core/search/A12Core /A12Core/
COPY --chown=solr:solr ./create-a12core.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

USER solr

RUN chmod -R a+X /A12Core
```

The folder `A12Core` contains the solr config files for the core. And the script `create-a12core.sh` to create the core is:

```
#!/bin/bash

solr-precreate A12Core /A12Core
```

The `/A12Core` dir contains the following files:

```
./core.properties
./conf
./conf/update-script.js
./conf/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt
./conf/schema.xml
./conf/spellings.txt
./conf/solrconfig.xml
./conf/currency.xml
./conf/mapping-FoldToASCII.txt
./conf/_schema_analysis_stopwords_english.json
./conf/stopwords.txt
./conf/synonyms.txt
./conf/elevate.xml
./conf/lang
./conf/lang/stopwords_en.txt
./conf/lang/stopwords_de.txt
```

However when starting an image build with the above Dockerfile and script an infinite loop seems to be created. The output is:

```
/opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-foreground: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-a12core.sh
Executing /opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate A12Core /A12Core
/opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-a12core.sh
Executing /opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate A12Core /A12Core
/opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-a12core.sh
Executing /opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate A12Core /A12Core
/opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-a12core.sh
...
```

How do I create a core using the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` extension mechanism?

Comment: Need more information .. Is A12Core  in line number 4 "./services-core/search/A12Core" is a core file ..? and  provide sample core file to check.

Comment: @Prem At least for the current scope of the question the exact core files seem not be be required because the problem is the infinite loop. But I might provide example files later on today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provide precreate-core file location which is to be executed, so edit create-a12core.sh as given below

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /opt/docker-solr/scripts/precreate-core  A12Core /A12Core
```

Tested and Works !!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to let the bounty expire. I already have started a new one to award it to you as soon as the system lets me.